# Use of custom authenticationManager and daoAuthenticationProvider beans

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i am running small spring mvc 3 application (Spitter from spring in action 3 book ) which is downloaded from github . In spring security file they have written beans for authenticationManager and daoAuthenticationProvider like this

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/home*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/spitters/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check"
        login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/home"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:property name="providers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

or this link  https://github.com/karolgornicki/spitter/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml

What is the use of these two beans authenticationManager and daoAuthenticationProvider . After commenting also this application works perfectly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `AuthenticationManager` delegates the fetching of persistent user information to one or more `AuthenticationProviders`. The authentication-providers (`DaoAuthenticationProvider`, `JaasAuthenticationProvider`, `LdapAuthenticationProvider`, `OpenIDAuthenticationProvider` for example) specialize in accessing specific user-info repositories. Something else is mentioned in [this part](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-manager) of the reference manual. It says:

You may want to register additional `AuthenticationProvider` beans with the `ProviderManager` and you can do this using the element with the ref attribute, where the value of the attribute is the name of the provider bean you want to add.

In other words, you can specify multiple `AuthenticationProviders`, for example one that looks for users in an `LDAP` database and another that looks in an SQL database.

Comment: You are correct but in above xml file why they have added authenticationManager and daoAuthenticationProvider beans. Without adding this beans also this application work perfectly because we have added user-service-ref="userDetailsService" in <authentication-manager> tag . I think no need to add this two beans again .

Comment: @NileshKhaire Yes correct, but the providers are just addons from Spring to connect and validate against LDAP and other databases.